# Render GDI to video file

Tags: video, gdi

Is there a way to render a GDI application directly to a video file? In other words, instead of painting to a device context for the screen can I get some kind of device context for an AVI or MPG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come up with a native winapi solution, but I ended up using libav to generate the video, copying the raster data from the device context into the video frame. It's not very elegant, but it's fairly straight forward once you know how to use libav.